# Getting access to an existing ActorSystem inside a trait

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray, traits

I'm using Spray for REST endpoints. 
How can I get access to an existing `ActorSystem` inside a trait?
I don't want to create a new `ActorSystem` inside my trait (if possible) but rather *reuse* my existing `ActorSystem`. I'm using [this](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala) Redis client library.

```
trait MySprayService extends HttpService with Json4sSupport {

   //the following line requires an implicit ActorSystem 
   val redis = RedisClient(ip,port) 
   ....
   ....
   val simpleRoute = path("simple" / "route") {
       get {
          complete {
             //use Redis here
          }
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create abstract method which returns ActorSystem and then deliver implementation in a class which will extends this trait.

```
trait MySprayService extends HttpService with Json4sSupport {

       implicit def as: ActorSystem 
       //the following line requires an implicit ActorSystem 
       val redis = RedisClient(ip,port) 
       ....
       ....
       val simpleRoute = path("simple" / "route") {
           get {
              complete {
                 //use Redis here
              }
           }
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to achieve the same is by using the self-type annotations.

```
trait MySprayService extends HttpService with Json4sSupport {
    this: Actor =>
    implicit val sys = context.system
    val redis = RedisClient(ip,port) 
    .....
```

With the self-type declaration, you are specifying that a class extending from this trait will have to also extend from Actor (which it will anyway do to run the route). Otherwise the compiler will generate an error. After the self-type declaration, you can go ahead and use any of the members of Actor.

This way, there are no extra methods to implement.